# Add a RANK column to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I use the following code for a query, that returns values by RANK.
I would like to add a RANK column for this query to the table,
Would really appreciate any help please.

Thanks.

```sql
SELECT meetingDate, 
       courseId, 
       raceNumber,
       preRaceMasterRating,
       RANK() OVER(Partition By meetingdate, courseId, raceNumber ORDER BY preRaceMasterRating DESC) preRaceMasterRating_Rank

FROM [2_TF_Entries];
```

Comment: `ALTER TABLE [2_TF_Entries] ADD COLUMN preRaceMasterRating_Rank bigint` then you update based on your `select` query?

Answer (score 1):

Change in any of these column `meetingdate, courseId, raceNumber` values,will require you to update table again,i would go with a view

```
create view vwname as
SELECT meetingDate, 
       courseId, 
       raceNumber,
       preRaceMasterRating,
       RANK() OVER(Partition By meetingdate, courseId, raceNumber ORDER BY preRaceMasterRating DESC) preRaceMasterRating_Rank
FROM [2_TF_Entries];
```